# Sampling rate for PID control to balance an inverted pendulum using 8051 - AT89c51rc2

Tags: accelerometer, dac, 8051, sampling

I want to control a dc motor(to balance an inverted ;endulum)
I want to sample the input from sensors(e.g.: ADXL345) and convert it to digital using a DAC. 
The maximum output data rate(ODR) for sensor ADXL is 3200Hz.The input sampling rate and the output control data rate to the motor should be high but not too high as the processor needs time to perform PID control calculations as well. 
But how to calculate the sampling rate and the output control data rate to motor  taking these into account?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends on the dynamics of your system, which you haven't told us anything about.  It really comes down to the height of your inverted pendulum.  The shorter (from pivot to center of mass), the faster it will respond and the faster the control loop needs to be.

Assuming this is a human-scale pendulum, maybe 1 foot to 1/2 meter or so, my gut feel says run the control loop every 10 ms for starters.  Significant things should be happening on the time scale of a few 100 ms, so 10 ms loop time seems about right.  You generally want to run the loop 20-50 times per first order time constant.

The tradeoffs are that faster loop time gives you more granularity, but too fast means the D term will see mostly noise, and the I contributions will very small relative to the output value.  Let's say for speed and simplicity, you use floating point with 16 bit mantissa.  If the I contributions are so small that they are 1000 times smaller than the accumulated value, then you're down to 6 bits of I each contribution.  That might still be OK, but I wouldn't want to go below that.  You can throw more bits (and therefore more cycles) at the I resolution problem, but you can't fix the D term seeing mostly noise or individual sensor steps (quantization noise).

You seem to be assuming that sampling rate and loop rate are the same.  They shouldn't be.  I would try to sample the sensors much faster than the loop period, like maybe every 100 to 500 µs, depending on what you A/Ds and sensors can do.  Then apply two poles of low pass filtering to the sensor values, but keep the step response time to at least 80% or so in one loop time.

The advantage of filtering is that you attenuate the high frequencies that won't help to control the plant, but will cause jitter and other problems.  It also reduces the quantization noise, and even gets you a extra bit or two maybe due to any one reading being the result of a number of input samples.

For example, let's say you can sample all the inputs once every 200 µs.  With two poles of low pass filtering using a filter fraction [FILT <-- FILT + FF(NEW - FILT), where FF is the filter fraction] of 1/16 (multiply by FF is shift right 4 bits), then you get 83% settling in your loop period of 10 ms.  But, no one sample contributes more than about 2.5% to the output.

Yes, there is high-fallutin math to compute all this up front as some of the other answers have shown.  However, the problem with that is usually having to know things about your system you don't know and can't easily measure.  Starting at a reasonable place and then tweaking as necessary is usually simpler and and quicker.  However, you have to actually *understand* what's going on, else you're just pecking at it in the dark.

Comment: This is a lovely answer. The sort of stuff that should be taught in school.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is of course 'sufficient'.

What's sufficient?

You have a closed loop control system. If you have a sensor read period of t seconds, you have a control latency of a minimum of t/2 seconds due to that alone. If your maths uses pipelining, that will add more cycles. Your motor control DAC will add another t/2 latency.

The control latency will add a phase shift to your control loop, this will tend to destabilise your loop, in addition to all the other phase shifts you are fighting.

As a rule of thumb, you don't want control latency to be contributing more than 10 to 20 degrees or so of additional phase margin at the unity gain crossover frequency. There's little benefit to be gained to get it much below 10 degrees, you will have to work hard on other phase shift elements if it's much more than 20 degrees.

Therefore, as an upper limit, you want the sum of your sampling, computation and motor drive latency to be <1/(20*f0dB), where f0dB is your unity gain crossover frequency.

What's your f0dB? The longer the pendulum, the lower your f0dB can be, and the slower you will be able to sample before you hit instability.

I strongly recommend you model the system you are intending to build. Matlab (if you have access to it) or Octave are good choices, I like to use Python with numpy, scipy and matplotlib, though you could force a circuit simulator or even a spreadsheet to do it. And find out what should happen in an ideal system, before you let the real world loose on it. Once in the simulator, you can add extra latency, and see what works.

Answer (score 0):

[image]If you have the possibility to get the sensor at high speed (3200sps), you can additionaly filter those data (FIR or IIR) to get smooth data. About sampling speed, Bobal: Digital Self-tuning controllers: